# how to call the column from main table whose id is being passed as foreign_id in pivot_table in laravel 8?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, forms

I am facing an issue while taking columns from the main table and pivot table.
So I have two tables name: users and roles and a pivot table called role_user.
here is the migration of users table:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Here is the migration of role:**

```
Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('slug')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

And here is the migration of pivot table:

```
Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
    $table->id();
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id');
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

And here is the data in the role_user table in PHPMyAdmin:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exOdg.jpg)

and here are the relationships:
users:

```
public function roles() {
     return $this->belongsToMany(role::class,'role_user','role_id','user_id')->using(RoleUser::class);
}
```

**And roles:**

```
public function users() {   
   return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'role_user','user_id','role_id')->using(RoleUser::class);
}
```

But now the main thing is I have to show them in table form, where  I have to show the name of the user associated with the name of a role assigned to it.

like, User, is tom and role is admin.
how to exactly show them via name in tabular form?
any help? how to solve it?

should I call role_user table and call user under foreach or use pivot method to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So at the part where you want to list the roles for a user you can do something like this in the blade.

```
@foreach($users as $user)
<tr>
    <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
    <td>
        @foreach($user->roles as $role)
            {{$role->name}}
        @endforeach
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

If you only need the timestamps you could use

```
$this->belongsToMany(role::class,'role_user','role_id','user_id')
    ->using(RoleUser::class)->withTimestamps();
```

Or create a model to directly interact with the role_user table.

Comment: thanks brother , but I have to do this with role_user table, as I stated above and from the picture that has given where role_id and user_id has been saved

Comment: So is it that you need the timestamps? You can always create a model which uses that table to make this easier?

Comment: hey there ... could you help me in solving this question : https://stackoverflow.com/q/68373453/16445004   struggling since week for solving this